# How to solve java.lang.SecurityException while trying to take a photo using camera in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

I am trying to take a photo in kotlin with the following function:

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun generate() {
    val photoUri = Uri.fromFile(photo)
    val imageCaptureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
    startActivityForResult(imageCaptureIntent, GO_TO_CARD_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

My manifest has following permissions and features granted:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

When starting the activity an exception is shown in Logcat:
"java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera". The camera application does not even start. How to solve this error? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Remove the `CAMERA` permission. You do not need that to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CAMERA` permission is if you are using the camera directly in your app, via the Android SDK's camera API or libraries around them. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` launches an external camera app — *that* app uses the API and needs the permission. So, the simplest solution is to remove the `CAMERA` permission.

Comment: What if you need the `CAMERA` permission for a different flow in the app though?

Comment: @Vibin: Then you would need to request the permission at runtime before using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.